# Umbraco 7 not loading class library

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

I have a visual studio 2015 project using umbraco 7.5.11 installed thru nuget, and 
write a class inheritance ApplicationEventHander place under App_Code. The ApplicationStarted method triggered and work properly.

After move the class to another class library project, and reference it from the original project, it is not fired anymore.

I experience the same problem when extend other class, like TreeController, IApplication.

Any pointers?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure the dll of the class library is present in the bin folder? Also does it use the same .Net framework as the web solution?

Comment: Both project is target .net framework 4.5.2. The web project bin folder has the class library. I remove it and rebuild, it show up again.

Comment: I think that could be a namespace issue. For example you could have your Config/trees.config with a wrong type="MyNamespace.myTree, MyAssembly"

Comment: Have you installed Umbracocms.core into your class library?

Comment: @Eyescream, when a treecontroller put under app_code, umbraco detect it and automatic add a entry in Config/trees.config. Then I delete the entry, move the treecontroller to class library, umbraco not recognize it. Even manually add back the entry with correct assembly name, umbraco don't display it

Comment: @Mivaweb, I have, otherwise I can't compile it.